# angular 6 ngModel with radio button not passing any data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, radio-button

I'd like to link radio buttons inside a form to an object, i cant get it to work!

I am linking ngModel to a variable of type string that is called presentation

I dont know what am I missing? even when i copy a working example it wont work in my form!

here is part of my form that I think is dysfunctional:
HTML:

```
<div class="uk-margin-large-right">

  <div class="uk-flex-inline ">
    <span class="uk-form-label uk-margin-small-right uk-text-bold "> Presentation </span>
    <label  class="uk-margin-medium-right">
      <input class="uk-radio " type="radio" name="radio1" value="Cephalic" [(ngModel)]="presentaion"> Cephalic  </label>
    <label class="uk-margin-medium-right">
      <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="Breech" [(ngModel)]="presentaion"> Breech </label>
      <label class="uk-margin-medium-right">
        <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="Transverse lie" [(ngModel)]="presentaion"> Transverse lie </label>

  </div>
  <p>this is {{presentation}}</p>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommService } from '../services/comm.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {


  user = {
    Doctor: '',
    Patient: '',
    Type:'',
    Report: ''
  };

  presentation:'';


  constructor(private CommService: CommService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.CommService.setData(this.user);
    console.log(this.presentation);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it like this if you want to give it initial value

```
  presentaion:string = 'Cephalic';

  log() {  // log the value to console
    console.log(this.presentaion)
  }
```

Template

```
   <p>this is {{presentaion}}</p>
   <button (click)="log()">Log the value to console</button>
```

> in your example there was a typo with the property name `<p>this is {{presentation}}</p>` just change it to **presentaion**

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrlbgc)

Comment: thanks, but this is not the problem, i can give it initial value just fine, but i want the value to change according to which radio button is clicked

Comment: the value will be in presentaion  check the example if you click on another radio the value of presentaion   will change

Comment: in the example  I have  create a method to log the value to console @HasanAli

Comment: it is a nice example, however, i copied it to my form and the value wont change when a click on a different radio! it just remains the same

Comment: in your example check   <p>this is {{presentation}}</p> the varible is wrong it 's presentaion

Comment: oh snap! this is embarrassing, you sir have sharp eyes, thanks for the help

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: can you consider accept my answer as it solve the problem @HasanAli ?